# Unity calling method from another class

Tags: unity-game-engine, nullpointerexception, singleton

I am getting a null pointer exception when I try to change a Textures color from another script.

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Works if in same file.

```
SwapColor(myTex, Color.black, Color.green,1f);
```

Gives null pointer exception

```
//PartsColorCustomizer.Instance.SwapColor(myTex, Color.black, Color.green, 1f);
```

This is the method im trying to call in another class called PartsColorCustomizer

```
public void SwapColor(Texture2D tex, Color original, Color swap, float threshold)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < tex.width; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < tex.height; y++)
        {
            Color col = tex.GetPixel(x, y);
            bool r = Mathf.Abs(original.r - col.r) <= threshold;
            bool g = Mathf.Abs(original.g - col.g) <= threshold;
            bool b = Mathf.Abs(original.b - col.b) <= threshold;
            bool a = Mathf.Abs(original.a - col.a) <= threshold;
            if (r && g && b && a)
            {

                //tex.SetPixel(x, y, swap);
            }
            if (col == Color.white) {
                tex.SetPixel(x, y, swap);
            }
            if (col == Color.magenta)
            {
                tex.SetPixel(x, y, swap);
            }
        }
    }
    tex.Apply();
}
```

what I set up for instance

```
 void Awake()
{
    if (_Instance != null)
    {
        _Instance = this;
        //LoadJson();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you trying to call PartsColorCustomizer.Instance.SwapColor from? It's possible that PartsColorCustomizer has not been initialized yet, if you are calling it from a Start or Awake that happens first.

Comment: I edited above and I call the PartsColorCustomizer.Instance.SwapColor(myTex, Color.black, Color.green, 1f); in the other classes start method

Comment: Is there an enabled GameObject with a `PartsColorCustomizer` script on it at scene start?

Comment: both scripts are attached to an active gameobject in the scene @Ruzihm

Comment: Oh silly me. Try `if (_Instance == null) { _Instance = this;}`

Comment: Wow i thought is was something simple.... Should I use == in all classes I want to use in other classes and not != ? What is the difference when calling a class with == and != instance?

Comment: @user3277468 `x == null` evaluates as `true` if `x` is currently `null`. You **want** to set `_Instance = this` precisely when `x` is `null`, because that's what it is at the start of the application. `x != null` evaluates as `false` when `x` is null, so most likely, control was never entering into that block! Also, be sure to @ the person you're replying to or they don't get the notification, unless it's a comment on their question/answer ;)